# Settings the title from inside a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, navigation

I'm working on a simple application with 3 tabs at the moment, the first tab is a UITableViewController, the other 2 are UIViewControllers.

Now from inside both UIViewControllers, I can set self.title and the title of the navbar will change.
But if I try this from inside the UITableViewController, this doesn't work, why is this?

I'm also trying to set a custom background for the navigation bar, after checking some tutorials, I found that this should work, but it really doesn't

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bgNavigationBar.png"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"Your Title";
```

should work, just put it in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
}
```

of the UITableViewController

Comment: Indeed, if I put it in viewDidLoad it works, doesn't seem to work in the init function